# Why didn't the ministry of magic call for help from foreign counterparts?

Tags: harry-potter

Why didn't the British ministry of magic call upon their foreign counterparts for aid in the war against Voldemort, I mean if they had the help from one other country they could gain the upper hand way quicker just through sheer numbers.

Comment: hmm okay im going to have to do some research, Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For quite a while the Ministry wouldn't even admit there was a problem (reference: from the tail end of *Goblet of Fire* to the tail end of *the Order of the Phoenix*), and Scrimgeour (speculation warning) probably thought himself capable of handling the job.

By the time it was obvious that it was too big for the natives to handle, it was too late to call for help.